# How can I apply formatting to some specific text in SQLite?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-sql

I am developing a small app.  I used internal SQLite java class to store data. Data is successfully stored and displaying. I used card-view and recyclerview. All things are working fine. But  I want to apply formatting on specif text, which is stored in sqlite. For example some text display as heading , bold etc . Actually text is to large. So i want text display as stylish.  I hope you understand my question. Sorry for bad English.

[Screen Shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNDrE.png)

Comment: Do you control the sqlite database or do you get the database from a server?

Comment: No . I am using internal java-class to store data.

Answer (score 0):

You can user basic HTML and turn it into a spanned using [`SpannableString.fromHtml`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int)). then set that Spannable String in a text view and will will show as a stylized html.